# react-share image not showing when shared

Tags: reactjs, react-share

in my all my share-buttons my images are not showing just the url

in my my public folder html header

```
    <meta content="`%PUBLIC_URL%/${picture.jpg}`">
    <meta property="og:description" content='' />
```

and in my details component i am using react-helmet t dynamically put the title where the share buttons.

```
  render() { 
    const { project, auth } = this.props;
    const shareUrl = window.location.href; 
    const articleId = this.props.match.params.id; 
    const {pathname} = this.props.location;
    const imageURL = '';

    if (project) {

      return (
        <div className="container">
```

The helmet component

```
          <Helmet>
              <meta charSet="utf-8" />
              <title>{project.title}</title>
              <meta property="og:url" content={`https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2F${shareUrl?shareUrl:''}`} />
              <meta property="og:description" content={project.title} />
              <meta property="og:image" content={imageURL!==''?`${project.pictureUrl}`: ''} />
              <meta property="fb:app_id" content="198985484382564" />
          </Helmet>
```

when  share to facebook this what i get

Eight killed in Sudan as protesters clash with Police https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dsdnewsapi.appspot.com/o/projectPics%2F824b9ec1-e708-455e-acce-9bbd40d2b24a.JPG?alt=media&token=137f1738-5cc3-4596-8373-d74f6699799a

just the image url but the image not showing.

```
            <FacebookShareButton
              url={shareUrl}
              imageURL={project.pictureUrl}
              quote={project.title} 
              className="m-2">
              <FacebookIcon size={32} round={true} />
            </FacebookShareButton>
```

And google plus is 
https://plus.google.com/up/?continue=https://plus.google.com/share?url%3Dhttps://dsdnews.de/project/xLJZmsOUZTI00Z7bmblo

```
            <GooglePlusShareButton
              url={shareUrl}
              title={project.title}
              media={project.pictureUrl}
              className="m-2">
              <GooglePlusIcon size={32} round={true} />
            </GooglePlusShareButton>
```

for twitter this is what  am getting

BREAKING NEWS... BUHARI`S 76 BIRTHDAY AND INVITEES SAGA. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dsdnewsapi.appspot.com/o/projectPics%2Ff862995d-f93f-4684-8ad4-52e2fde6324c.png?alt=media&token=287de96d-b2b8-4c7d-a327-5143f7ad4ac5

https://dsdnews.de/project/xLJZmsOUZTI00Z7bmblo

```
            <TwitterShareButton
              url={shareUrl}
              title={`${project.title} ${project.pictureUrl}`}
              media={project.pictureUrl}
              className="m-2">
              <TwitterIcon size={32} round={true} />
            </TwitterShareButton>
```

and whatsappp is

BREAKING NEWS... BUHARI`S 76 BIRTHDAY AND INVITEES SAGA. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dsdnewsapi.appspot.com/o/projectPics%2Ff862995d-f93f-4684-8ad4-52e2fde6324c.png?alt=media&token=287de96d-b2b8-4c7d-a327-5143f7ad4ac5

https://dsdnews.de/project/xLJZmsOUZTI00Z7bmblo

```
            <WhatsappShareButton
              url={shareUrl}
              title= {`${project.title} ${project.pictureUrl}`}
              media={project.pictureUrl}
              className="m-2">
              <WhatsappIcon size={32} round={true} />
            </WhatsappShareButton>

            <LinkedinShareButton
              url={shareUrl}
              title={project.title}
              media={project.pictureUrl}
              className="m-2">
              <LinkedinIcon size={32} round={true} />
            </LinkedinShareButton>

            <EmailShareButton
              url={shareUrl}
              title={project.title}
              media={project.pictureUrl}
              className="Demo__some-network__share-button m-2">
              <EmailIcon size={32} round={true} />
            </EmailShareButton>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      )
    } 

  }
```